# USB 3G Modem for embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, modem, 3g

I have to develop an application on embedded Linux which sends data over Internet. I have to choose a USB 3G modem with a SIM card holder, which works successfully or is supported on embedded Linux.

Comment: Do you have any preference for instance?

Comment: I have seen a few from Huawei and one of them is E372. They have not mentioned anything on their website about its support on Linux though!

Answer (score 5):

Most 3G modems are supported in Linux. I've used several different models, mostly Huawei, on embedded devices using standard Linux packages and libraries - they all  do pretty much the same thing, just with brighter lights or faster stripes. Good starting points are `wvdial` and `pppd`.

The main obstacle to overcome is working out the individual methods each provider uses for authentication and access, but this is generally well documented. The [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) pages on configuring `wvdial` and `pppd` are pretty good:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem

Comment: Million thanks, I will start working on it very soon and post my prblems if I find any.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of USB "hotspot" devices exist now ("wingles"), and so do $1 USB wifi adapters that are well supported on linux.  If you can plug both devices in, you get a really no-hassle way to do linux networking, with the bonus that you can easily share it too if you need.

Here's 2 good references for setting up:
http://greyfocus.com/2018/01/wifi-without-networkmanager/ and https://linuxconfig.org/connect-to-wifi-from-the-linux-command-line/